# Problem with foreign key between 3 tables. (PgAdminIII)

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-3

I'm using pgAdmin III for PostgreSQL but I have a problem with foreign keys between 3 tables. My tables are:

**Locale** with a **primary key IDnegozio** (integer type, no need to make it serial type)
**Orario** with a **primary key IDorario** (integer type, no need to make it serial type)
**OrarioToLocale** with two columns: **IDlocaleT** & **IDorarioT** (both integer).

I'm trying to make a foreign key between IDlocale -> IDlocaleT and IDorario -> IDorarioT so, I can have the relation that a Shop can have multiples time.
The problem is that when I try to make these foreign keys, and an error occurs me: 
"no unique constraint matching is given keys for referenced table" and I don't understand why. I tried to google but I didn't find any answer!
How can I do?

This is the code of the three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE public."Locale"
(
  "IDnegozio" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"Locale_IDnegozio_seq"'::regclass),
  CONSTRAINT "Locale_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("IDnegozio"),
)

CREATE TABLE public."Orario"
(
  "IDorario" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"Orario_IDorario_seq"'::regclass),
  CONSTRAINT "Orario_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("IDorario")
)

CREATE TABLE public."OrarioToLocale"
(
  "IDlocaleT" integer NOT NULL,
  "IDorarioT" integer NOT NULL
)
```

How can I do? Thank you advice!

Comment: never use `"` for identifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this right into the `CREATE TABLE` statements, and this can be a lot easier and shorter than what you have.

```
CREATE TABLE public.Locale ( IDnegozio serial PRIMARY KEY );
CREATE TABLE public.Orario ( IDorario serial PRIMARY KEY );
CREATE TABLE public.OrarioToLocale (
  IDlocaleT integer NOT NULL REFERENCES Locale,
  IDorarioT integer NOT NULL REFERENCES Orario,
  PRIMARY KEY ( IDlocaleT, IDorarioT )
)
```

I made OrarioToLocale with a composite primary but,

1. You may decide you don't want that.
2. If you do want that, than IDlocaleT, and IDorarioT are `NOT NULL` which means that even that doesn't need to be explicit.

Answer (score 1):

It would have been good if you provided the foreign keys that failed. The following should work:

```
ALTER TABLE public."OrarioToLocale"
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_... FOREIGN KEY ("IDorarioT")
        REFERENCES public."Orario" ("IDorario");
```

and a similar constraint for Locale. Why do the attributes in OrarioToLocale end with a T?

Comment: "Why do the attributes in OrarioToLocale end with a T?"It's just for simplicity of reading, so I distinguish the fields.